How to simulate LEFT and RIGHT functions in ABAP CDS 7.40?
The Eclipse (version June 2023 release) is showing a syntax error on the below SAP CDS view, I am unable to save/activate it in our SAP ECC system, but exactly the same code is saving/activating fine in another SAP system but it's a S/4HANA system.
The error red mark I am seeing is at LEFT and RIGHT syntax in the below CASE statement:

Unexpected word left
Unexpected word right

If I remove the whole CASE statement, then it's saving and activating fine. Please let us know how can we achieve the same goal in our SAP ECC system? Thanks.
@AbapCatalog.sqlViewName: 'YSD_SHP'
@AbapCatalog.compiler.compareFilter: true
@AbapCatalog.preserveKey: true
@AccessControl.authorizationCheck: #NOT_REQUIRED
@EndUserText.label: 'SHP data extract'
define view ZSD_SHP_EXTRACT as select from prps
    inner join proj as proj on proj.pspnr = prps.psphi
{
    key prps.pspnr as pspnr,
        prps.objnr as OBJNR,
    case left( prps.objnr, 2 )
     when 'PR' then right( prps.objnr, 8 )
     else ''
     end as WBS,
     prps.prart as prart,
     prps.psphi as psphi,
     proj.pspid as pspid
}


The message is coming from the ABAP CDS compiler so it's not a matter of Eclipse version, it's a matter of ABAP version, which is obviously different between your two ABAP systems.
LEFT and RIGHT have been added to CDS Views in ABAP 7.50 (see the modification 3).
The solution is very simple: use the function SUBSTRING which exists since the beginning of CDS Views in ABAP 7.40.

Got it, thank you. I tried to apply SUBSTRING function in the above CDS code but not successful in CASE statement scenario. Could you pls. provide me code snippet of SUBSTRING in CASE statement

There is an example in the documentation. What is the issue? Edit your question, append the code you have tried, tell what the issue is. Note that PRPS-OBJNR is 22 characters and the values starting with PR are always like PR00000000 (8 digits right after PR), so you may also extract the 8 characters from the 3rd character.

Why do you want the answer to be accepted? To make other people lifes' easier raising their chances to find a good answer? Probably the OP comes from that other offiial site ;-)
